# How to fix 3584 alignment offset issue during installation

Tags: system-installation, hdd

So I made the acquisition of a Seagate Backup Plus Slim to use as an external hard-drive for a laptop that years later now refuses to acknowledge either the internal HDD or SSD.

I'm having issues during installation

> The partition /dev/sda1 assigned to / starts at an offset of 3584
>   bytes from the minimum alignment for this disk, which may lead to very
>   poor performance.
>
> Since you are formatting this partition, you should correct this
>   problem now by realigning the partition, as it will be difficult to
>   change later. To do this, go back to the main partitioning menu,
>   delete the partition, and recreate it in the same position with the
>   same settings. This will cause the partition to start at a point best
>   suited for this disk.

I attempted to follow the instructions and after hours of attempting to solve this issue I've gotten nowhere. I'm frustrated and just want this to work.

Edit: while i'd much prefer using ext4 since most distros i've used default to that, using a different file system seems to work. Xfs was specified from what I found and that worked. If you're having the same problem this is the closest to a fix I've been able to find.

TL;DR if you get this error use xfs instead it seems to work just fine.

Comment: It's a 1 TB Drive btw, that might be helpful information.

Comment: I read somewhere that going with the XFS file format works. I'm trying that and it seems to work, but I'd really prefer being able to use ext4 like I usually do.

Comment: Please add how you solved your problem separately as **Answer** from the box down bellow.